# How can I remove the "Advanced" panel of all blocks in WordPress block editor?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to optimize the WordPress block editor for my clients and hide everything that might confuse my clients. I've already removed several panels (colors, typography, etc.) via the theme.json (by deactivating all the available options within that panels), but I can't figure out how to remove the "Advanced" panel that has "HTML anchor" and "Additional CSS class(es)". How can I remove this panel? It would be great if there is a clean way to do this. Any ideas?

It can also be a Javascript or PHP solution if needed.

Comment: I don’t have a solution, just an opinion. In the past I used to "clean up" WordPress, too, to make it simpler for my clients. Eventually they’d hire someone who "knew WordPress" and was confused because features appeared to be missing, or things were in different places. The changes also occasionally conflicted with other plugins. Having built dozens upon dozens of sites now, I’ve found my clients are actually pretty savvy and I personally wouldn’t recommend doing this. No judgment, just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion and valuable feedback! That's a good point! However, actually I simplified the reason why I do this. In fact I have a few more reasons and the WordPress installation will definitely stay under my control, so the problems you mentioned are not that big in my specific case. Nevertheless, I was very happy about your feedback! Usually makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This can also likely be done in javascript, possibly using the `addfilter` hook.

You can use the poorly documented [block_type_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/block_type_metadata/) hook although this strategy below will only work with blocks that have [supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/) in the block's block.json file . (All of the core blocks included by default with WordPress have this).

```
add_filter( 'block_type_metadata', 'remove_the_class_anchor' );
function remove_the_class_anchor($metadata ) {
    $metadata['supports']['customClassName'] = false;
    $metadata['supports']['anchor'] = false;
    return $metadata;
}
```